Show a polynomial in two variables is irreducible
Show that the polynomial $P\in\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ given by $P(x,y)=x^3+xy^2+x+y$ is irreducible.

I have to prove this using elementary techniques
So, let's asume $P$ is reducible, meaning there exist polynomials of positive degree $f,g\in \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$ such that $P=f\cdot g$.
I can consider the degree in $y$ on each side of $P(x,y)=f(x,y)\cdot g(x,y)$. Clearly, we have that
$$dg_y(f)+dg_y(g)=2=dg_y(P).$$
Now, I can split this into three cases:

$dg_y(f)=2$ and $dg_y(g)=0$
$dg_y(f)=0$ and $dg_y(g)=2$
$dg_y(f)=1=dg_y(g)$

Case 1:
$$f(x,y)=q(x,y)y+r(x),$$
$$g(x,y)=g(x).$$ Here $dg_y(q)=1$.
Since $P=f\cdot g$, then
$$x^3+x+y(xy+1)=\left(q(x,y)y+r(x)\right)g(x)\\
=q(x,y)g(x)y+r(x)g(x).$$
Comparing both sides of the previous equation give me that $x^3+x=r(x)g(x)$ and $y(xy+1)=q(x,y)g(x)y$.
The problem is, I don't see how to arrive at a contradiction in these three cases. So far this I what I've done.
Another particular question I have is: When expressing $f(x,y)$, should I do it as $f(x,y)=q(x,y)y+r(x)$ where $dg_y(q)=1$? Or should I express it as $f(x,y)=q(x)y^2+r(x)$?

To answer your last question first: It's fine to write $f=q(x,y)y+r(x)$, but not the most helpful for the problem. However, it's not possible to write $f(x,y)=q(x)y^2+r(x)$, because the polynomial on the right hand side doesn't have linear terms in $y$.

To show that $P$ is irreducible, let's continue your approach of looking at the $y$-degree. As you did, suppose first that $\deg_yf=2$ and $\deg_yg=0$. Write $$f=f_2(x)y^2+f_1(x)y+f_0(x),$$ then $$xy^2+y+x^3+x=fg=f_2(x)g(x)y^2+f_1(x)g(x)y+f_0(x)g(x).$$ In particular, comparing the $y$-coefficient, we see that $f_1(x)g(x)=1$, so $g$ is a unit, which is what we wanted to show.

The case $\deg_yf=\deg_yg=1$ can be handled similarly. Let $f=f_1(x)y+f_0(x)$ and $g=g_1(x)y+g_0(y)$, then \begin{equation}\tag{$\ast$}xy^2+y+x^3+x=fg=f_1(x)g_1(x)y^2+(f_1(x)g_0(x)+f_0(x)g_1(x))y+f_0(x)g_0(x).\end{equation} Comparing the $y^2$-coefficient, we have $f_1(x)g_1(x)=x$, which is irreducible. Wlog (rescale with units, and swap $f$ and $g$, if necessary) we may assume $f_1(x)=x$ and $g_1(x)=1$. Now for the linear term, we have \begin{equation}1=f_1(x)g_0(x)+f_0(x)g_1(x)=xg_0(x)+f_0(x).\tag{$\ast\ast$}\end{equation}
Together with $f_0g_0=x^3+x$ we see that neither polynomial can be $0$, and $\deg f_0+\deg g_0=3$, as well as $\deg(xg_0)=\deg f_0$, i.e. $\deg f_0=1+\deg g_0$. Thus $\deg g_0=1$ and $\deg f_0=2$. From $(\ast\ast)$ we know that $f_0$ has constant term $1$, and from $(\ast)$ it follows that $g_0$ doesn't have a constant term, otherwise $f_0(x)g_0(x)$ would have non-zero constant term. Therefore $g_0(x)=ax$ for some $a\in\mathbb Q$, and $f_0(x)=1-ax^2$ from $(\ast\ast)$. But then $f_0g_0=ax-a^2x^3\neq x+x^3$ for any $a$, contratiction.  $\square$

